# Failed to Resolve Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

My App Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.acer.simpleblog"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But its not syncing and showing the following error:

1. Failed to resolve---com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0
2. Failed to resolve---com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0

and like this they r failing to resolve database,storage and lifecycle.

This is happening only when i am connnecting with Firebase UI otherwise it is working fine.

Comment: Make sure your have updated google play service ...

Comment: please show your Project  build.gradle and module build.gradle files

Answer (score 0):

As noted [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) you have to add:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

To your root-level `build.gradle` file.

And

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

to your local app `build.gradle` file

Comment: Thanx.It worked

Comment: @ArunavaSaha please upvote and let others know that this solved your problem marking this as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you need to change this line of code:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.4.0'
```

with

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
```